# Is there a way to have a task Say before running Redirect?

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio Autopilot, and I have some local code that I am running from a redirect. However, it takes a few seconds to complete, and the caller sits in silence. If I place a Say statement before the Redirect, the Say is played directly before the Say in the Redirect code. Is there a way to force the Say to play at the start of the task, so that the caller knows something is going on in the background?

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "say": "Okay, let me check on that."
        },
        {
            "redirect": {
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "my url"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your say before the redirect doesn't play until the redirect returns too?

Comment: Correct. I have silence until the redirect finishes processing, then the 'say' will play, and it is immediately followed by what was returned in the 'redirect'.

Comment: Ok, this is intentional behaviour on Twilio's part for now. I'm following up with the team to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the help.